# What's the advantage of using Laravel Eloquent Relationship queries?

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

So I'm trying to improve my queries by implementing eloquent relationships.
Let's say I have a **threads** table and each thread have **replies**

What I need is a JSON object of the information of threads with array of all the replies.

Currently, I can achieve what I want with this.

```
public function show($threadId){
        $threads = ThreadView::find($threadId);
        $threads->replies = ReplyView::where('threadId', $threadId)->get();
        return response()->json($threads, 200);
    }
```

With eloquent relationship, I can achieve the same result with something like this.

```
public function show($threadId) {

    $threads= ThreadView::find($threadId);
    $threads->replies= ThreadView::find($threadId)->Replies;

    return response()->json($threads, 200);
}
```

Is there an advantage to using relationship? They both look the same to me.

Comment: Eager loading is where eloquent shines, imo. Makes querying related data a no brainer. Plus it reads nicely in code.

Comment: If I remember correctly, if you don't define replies to be a relationship, and end up saving your thread, it will try to save the field 'replies' and will blow up. Because when you query a relationship, it is not store within the attributes, but if you don't define the relationship and use `$threads->replies = ...`, it will store it as an attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Eloquent you can do this even shorter:

```
public function show($threadId) {
    $threads = ThreadView::with('replies')->find($threadId);
    return response()->json($threads, 200);
}
```

The [`with`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) function will eager load relations without you having to write the query.

That is the advantage of Eloquent, it writes the queries for you. No need to create join queries or extra queries for you.

Comment: Thanks for answering! This is what I'm looking for actually.

Comment: Glad I could help. Please consider marking this answer as the solution to your problem, this way other users might find this as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public function show($threadId) {

    $threads= ThreadView::with('replies')->find($threadId);

    return response()->json($threads, 200);
}
```

The main advantage is that using relationships like this, the first example does 2 selects (it grabs 100% of `ThreadView` then 100% of `ReplyView`), while the second example only does 1 query.

The second advantage is that Eloquent does a Really Good Job at lazy loading compared to others and it is much better to use if you are not an expert in SQL queries.

Ditching Eloquent models and using the [**DB Builder**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries) directly will be approximately 500x faster, and I find the code cleaner. That may be what you're looking for.

But if you use models, use the relationships!

Comment: Didn't the second function also did two queries?

Comment: Da,mmi.t My mind literally hallucinated the `with`. Good code review, bro!

Comment: Thanks for answering!